# Compute the integer part of $(1+2\cos 20 ^{\circ})^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, trigonometric-series

Is there a natural number $n$ such that the integral part of $(1+2\cos 20 ^{\circ})^n$ can be divided by $1000000$?

My thoughts. I know here is a well known propery [Prove that $\cos 20^{\circ} + \cos 100^{\circ} + \cos {140^{\circ}} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168706/prove-that-cos-20-circ-cos-100-circ-cos-140-circ-0)  but not sure how it could be applied

Or is there a better trick using the Euler formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a root of $x^3-3x^2+1=0$.  So $y_n=x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n$ obeys the recurrence relation
$$y_n=3y_{n-1}-y_{n-3}$$
and the other two roots of the cubic approach zero.